# Can any one tell me how to generate mail with jconsole values

Tags: jmx

I have configured jconsole to view jvm health.And I want to send an email to subscribers with jvm statics (which displayed by jconsole) can any one tell me how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the Management Console that comes [JRockit](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/jrockit/missioncontrol/index.html). It works like JConsole but it allows you to create triggers that can send an email when a JMX-attribute exceeds a threshold for a certain period of time. See this [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/tools/jmcpdfs/mc3/consnotify3.pdf) for more information.